# Nhibernate and not-exists query

Tags: nhibernate

I'm trying to construct a query in NHibernate to return a list of customers with no orders matching a specific criteria.

My Customer object contains a set of Orders:

```
<set name="Orders">
    <key column="CustomerID" />
    <one-to-many class="Order" />
</set>
```

How do I contruct a query using NHibernate's ICriteria API to get a list of all customers who have no orders?  Using native SQL, I am able to represent the query like this:

```
select * from tblCustomers c where not exists 
    (select 1 from tblOrders o where c.ID = o.CustomerID)
```

I have been unable to figure out how to do this using aliases and DetatchedCriteria objects.  Any guidance would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

this would translate to that sql...

```
session.CreateCriteria<Customer>("c")
    .Add(Subqueries.NotExists(
        DetachedCriteria.For<Order>("o")
        .SetProjection(Projections.Constant(1))
        .Add(Restrictions.PropertyEq("c.ID", "o.Customer.ID"))
        //Add more order restricitions here
    ))
    .List<Customer>();
```

if you only want customers with no orders you could also use `Restrictions.IsEmpty()` to do the exact same thing as above.

```
session.CreateCriteria<Customer>()
    .Add(Restrictions.IsEmpty("Orders"))
    .List<Customer>()
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this will get me started.  Will NHibernate complain about using o.CustomerID... that column is in the DB but isn't mapped as a column in my Order class.  (NHibernate added it automatically as specified in the Customer's set as the key column.)

Comment: Do both entitties have to be mapped to each other to make everything work? Cuz currently I can't enter the statement, even intellisense doesn't highlight it.

Comment: Just got it, Thanks so much, really saved me hours of search.

Comment: +1 I nearly created a gnarly detached subquery with aliases because my query is runtime dynamic, thankfully that's avoided with an elegant Restrictions.IsEmpty!